# Android task manager or system dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I would like to know is there a way to get events while displaying a System dialog (Such task manager, shut down alert,...).

I can close the system dialogs from my activity through intent like below

```
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```

But in my code I need to know a system dialog is shown over the screen (They can be Task manager/ Shut down dialog ...), so that I can invoke the above code for closing it.

I searched for intent filters nothing found.

Comment: add more information what you are tring to do..

Comment: Hi Dhaval Sodha Parmar, I have updated with more information

Comment: you are tring to close taskmanager programatically if it displaying on screen??? am i right??

Comment: No I don't want to kill the task manager application. I just need to restrict the user access to the task manager, by closing the alert dialog (Pop up while long pressing the HOME button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### put below method in your Actvity and check **recent app dialog close automatically**.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        Log.e("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

        if (!hasFocus) {
            Log.e("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

            Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }
```

### **Note: it only work for single Activity. not for all activity in your app.**

Comment: Thanks Dhaval, But I am facing problem with it. I am opening a browser session from my activity, Then the above method does not invoked because the current focused window is browser.

Comment: @anish: yes this heppend. but instead of open browser create new activity inside that put web view and open that link inside that activity in your app. its work.

Comment: Yes that is an alternative, but my project requirements doesn't allow to do like that. So its not possible to detect when a system dialog is shown am I right?

Comment: @anish: yes it is not possible.

Comment: So I am going for a back ground thread for sending close dialog broad cast repeatedly. I think that will work for me. Thank You Dhaval

Comment: How can i dismiss the runtime permission dialog??

Answer (score 0):

Use Broadcast-Receiver and place intent inside onreceive() method.Then register this receiver where you display your alert dialog. Then it automatically disable settings,recent apps button
----Nagesh