# Start blocking dialogs in service

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

Block all dialogs of Android, it means no dialog will appear, either of app or Android systems, until my service is running.  Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to just block all popups.

For me it makes sense that android doesn't allow that normally.

But you can try (if you really want:) )to make your app an [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.htm) which will react on popup displayed and immediately close it. To close the popup you can find some Cancel button on it and perform click or `performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);` (if its cancelable).

Check out some code here to find a popup: [Android unable read window content on few devices using accessibility service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391113/android-unable-read-window-content-on-few-devices-using-accessibility-service) (I don't know if that will work)

You can also review this to get some more inspiration on how to find a view and make clicks on any app with the Accessibility Service: [Programmatically enabling/disabling accessibility settings on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360198/programmatically-enabling-disabling-accessibility-settings-on-android-device/38613852#38613852)

---

**EDITED: Some more details**

You will need to follow this standard tutorial to add the service to your app: https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html

First thing to note is that you should decide to use xml configuration and include `android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"`like in the tutorial:

```
<accessibility-service
 android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused"
 android:packageNames="com.example.android.myFirstApp, com.example.android.mySecondApp"
 android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
 android:notificationTimeout="100"
 android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.apis.accessibility.TestBackActivity"
 android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
/>
```

and I think you will not need the line `android:packageName`

Then you need to experiment what should happen in the callback method - here is just my rough suggestion:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
   AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();        
   if(event.getEventType()==AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) 
       if(isAlert(source)) //explore the view (maybe recursively) to find if there is an alert
           performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
}
```

and the recursive method can be like

```
private boolean isAlert(AccessibilityNodeInfo view){

   int count = view.getChildCount();
   boolean result = false;
   for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
       AccessibilityNodeInfo child = view.getChild(i);
       if(child.getClassName().contains("Alert")){ 
            return true;
       }
       if (explore(child));
        result = true;
       child.recycle();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some boilerplate/ or helping code to do so , because i can't figure it out yet

Comment: ok, I've just quickly added some code with my idea for your issue.

Comment: i am still unable to replicate your idea