# How to dismiss System Alert Dialog consisting of Text View and Edit text?

Tags: android, ussd

I am successfully closing system alert dialog for some mobiles but i am not able to close alert dialog consisting of text view,edit text and button.Please Help me out.

Thanks.
[For image Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1iiM.png)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/24022680/1157879

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: @ nikhil how to remove focus of edit text in alertdialog ?