# Android: Dismiss System Generated Run-time user permission dialog box

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, user-permissions

I want to dismiss the system generated run time user permission programmatically.
 Is there any way??

Comment: Why do you want to do this? While you can possibly dismiss the alert, you cannot grant the requested permission with code.

Answer (score 0):

Send an intent with action of `Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`.

This is sent by the system when the HOME key is pressed and should close all dialogs.

---

The below code is copied from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022680/383414).

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (! hasFocus) {
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```