# Screen overlay detected - How to handle this in an screen overlay app

Tags: android, permissions, overlay

Some devices have extra security features and check if an app is drawing on top of others, when showing a permission dialog.

I have a sidebar app, and my app has to be disabled, before users can accept a system dialog.

**Questions**

- How am I supposed to handle this case?
- Is there a way to listen for an "System dialog shown" event, so that I can remove my sidebar and a "System dialog finished" so that I know, i can continue with my sidebar overlay? I know, that it's enough to stop the service (you don't have to remove the permission), so this would be a solution as well

**EDIT**

*One solution I can think of is following:*

Using the `AccessibilityService` to check current foreground apps/views. There I will be able to check events that show me current foreground activities and even views...

My problems:

- I don't know how to identify a permission dialog there.
- Secondly, this forces me to ask the user to get this permission (which I want to avoid, but having a solution with this service, would already be an improvement for me, because some users give this permission to my app already - I would have to ask all then and explain the reason, which is something I can live with).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, what you want isn't possible. In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964108/android-task-manager-or-system-dialog), there is a solution to detect system dialogs, but I don't think it will work for your overlay (only for the currently active activity).

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942366/on-android-how-to-detect-a-system-dialog-is-displayed-power-options-recent-ap) suggests that it may be possible to monitor system dialogs via the [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) class, but that API has been deprecated since LOLIPOP.

For these reasons, I suggest you to add a pause button to your overlay. Or even better, **use a sticky [notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)** with stop/start buttons so users can manually pause your overlay.

---

To identify system apps, you need the package name as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24634187/2829009):

```
public boolean isSystemApp(String packageName) {
    try {
        // Get packageinfo for target application
        PackageInfo targetPkgInfo = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(
                packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        // Get packageinfo for system package
        PackageInfo sys = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(
                "android", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        // Match both packageinfo for there signatures
        return (targetPkgInfo != null && targetPkgInfo.signatures != null && sys.signatures[0]
                .equals(targetPkgInfo.signatures[0]));
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll check the links... My app pauses itself sometimes already, when some user selected blacklisted apps are in the foreground, so I monitor this via `ActivityManager` (or the newer `AccessibilityService`) anyways already... I thought there may be a solution with the `AccessibilityService`at least...

Comment: @prom85 Yes, it might also be possible with [AccessibilityService#getWindows()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#getWindows()), which accordings to the documentation returns all windows shown.

Comment: I already have a pause/resume button in the notification... And getting the current foreground app/view is no problem, still, I don't know how to identify system windows... I've add some extra infos to my question related to the `AccessibilityService` solution...

Comment: I updated my answer with more info. Use the package name or the ApplicationInfo of the app to find out whether the app is a system app.

Comment: This would mean, my app gets disabled whenever a system app is in front (when you show your device settings, run a preinstalled system app like maybe facebook/google/gmail, as those are installed as system apps sometimes and many more)... that does not work... I need to identify the SYSTEM DIALOG WINDOW only, no matter which app is starting it...